# Highcharts graph width is incorrect when scrollbar is present, in bootstrap fluid span

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm not sure if this is a bootstrap or highcharts issue but I cannot seem to get my chart to size correctly; the initial chart width is too wide when both a scrollbar is present and in a bootstrap span.  Resizing the window never seems to produce widths that are too wide but sometimes they are too narrow.

Removing the code from the span construct seems to result in proper width in all situations so I am thinking that there may be some detrimental interaction between hc and bootstrap.

I made a fiddle to demonstrate, but keep in mind that your browser window will need to be short enough to cause a scrollbar:

http://jsfiddle.net/xEtherealx/Q5EGX/15/

Is there a way I can force the width to conform via css?  I can create a callback on window resize as a workaround but I would rather find a *proper* solution instead.

**Edit**: As suggested the following is a workaround, and could be called after some timeout or just once after page load:

```
    this.setChartSize = function() {
        chart.setSize( $(chart.container).parent().width(), $(chart.container).parent().height() );
        return false;
    };
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div id="toresize" class="span3" style="background: gray; overflow: auto;">
            <div class="targetpane">
                 <h4 class="text-center">HC Sizing Test</h4>

                <!-- take up space -->
                <div class="well well-small" style="height: 160px;"></div>

                <!-- Chart -->
                <div class="well well-small" style="padding: 5px;">
                    <div id="barchart" style="height: 160px; margin-bottom: 5px;"></div>
                </div>

                <!-- take up space -->
                <div class="well well-small" style="height: 160px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- span -->
        <div class="span9" style="background: gray;">
            <div class="myBorder">Some content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
.well
{
    background-color: #444;
}

.targetpane
{
    color: #888;
    background-color: #1B1B1B;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.bodycontainer {
    height: 50px !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'barchart',
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#toresize').height($(window).height() - 3);
    console.log($(window).height());
})
$(window).resize();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that when page is loaded width of container for Highcharts is different. I think it's due to rendering time (takes more than 1ms), so possible solution is to make sure chart has proper widht nad height after rendering: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5EGX/17/ (see console comments)

```
setTimeout(function() {
      chart.setSize($("#barchart").width(), $("#barchart").height());
}, 1);
```

Comment: I did something very similar to this, noted in the question just now.  I was suspecting that the problem was with the scrollbar itself; when it shows up, that dynamically resizes the chart's parent div but the chart does not pick up that resize.  I'd like to know if there is a less obtrusive way to handle this behavior though.

Comment: I'm not sure what Highcharts could change in that issue - width is taken from jQuery, which looks like is wrongly calculated. Maybe someone from bootstrap has an answerd for that issue.

Comment: I think that there is no other solution to this so marking it as accepted.  I see a somewhat related issue but it may not be highcharts specific: http://jsfiddle.net/xEtherealx/Q5EGX/18/

Comment: It's a pity there isn't a better way to do this.. it would be great if you could accomplish it with a Highcharts public API without using timeouts (I personally hate them).

Comment: Try also use `chart.reflow()` method. Should be fine. This isn't the problem with Highcharts, just overall problem.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding that per [Highcharts chart.event.load documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load):

> From version 2.0.4, there is also a second parameter to **Highcharts.Chart** where a callback function can be passed to be executed on chart.load.

Which is useful when you want to initialize like this:

```
    $("#chart").highcharts(options, function(e){
        setTimeout(function() {
            e.setSize(container.width(), container.height());
        }, 1);
```

Or, when you storing JSON configuration options, and don't want to carry around the weight of this repeated code.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could solve this in CSS by forcing the width of the .highcharts-loading class to be 100%. You have to add ! because the element gets a width set on an inline style.

```
        .highcharts-loading {
            width: 100% !important;
        }
```

Comment: Just to tell you, the inline style can be overridden using attributes, the `!important` declaration should to be used only in the last case. The overriding of the inline style in this situation so is `.highcharts-loading[style] {width: 100%;}`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with HighCharts and Bootstrap (charts were too wide if the scrollbar appeared after the charts were initialized).  I solved it by adding the following snippet in the `<head>` tag at the top of the page, forcing the vertical scrollbar to be shown immediately.

```
<style>
  body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
</style>
```