# Highcharts size in bootstrap modals with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts, angular-ui-bootstrap, highcharts-ng

I have a problem with highcharts and bootstrap modals.
The highcharts chart does not fit correctly inside the container.

[image]

The chart should has the width = 100% but it has width = 600px, the default modal width. This is not ok if you use the modal-sm, modal-lg, ... classes.

I have read another post about this and the solution is do a $(window).resize() call or use the highchart reflow method.

Ok. I'm tried this using the "rendered" promise of ui.bootstrap for angularjs, but the render produces a ng-class attribute inside the modal container with the modal size (modal-lg, modal-sm, ...).

This parameter is rendered in a real class="modal- lg" after this call.

You can test this:

```
 myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
   $scope.openModal = function() {
     var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
       animation: true,
       templateUrl: 'modal.html',
       controller: 'modalctrl',
       size: 'lg'
     })
     .rendered.then(function() {
       console.log('.modal-dialog').attr('class')
     });
   };
 });
```

This returns the main class "modal-dialog" but not the ng-class rendered.

I solved it with a not-ideal solution:

```
.rendered.then(function() {
  $('.modal-dialog').addClass('modal-xl');
  $(window).resize();
});
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Sources:

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/master/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myapp">
      <div ng-controller="myctrl">
        <button ng-click="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
  var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng", "ui.bootstrap"]);

  myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope, $uibModal) {
      $scope.openModal = function() {
          var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: true,
          templateUrl: 'modal.html',
          controller: 'modalctrl',
          size: 'lg'
        })
        .rendered.then(function() {
          $('.modal-dialog').addClass('modal-xl');
          $(window).resize();
        });
      };
  });

  myapp.controller('modalctrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.mychart = {
        options: {
          xAxis: {
            categories: [2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015]
          },
          title: 'demo',
        },
        series: [
          {name: 'serie1', data: [252, 259, 300, 312, 323, 354, 369, 378, 399]},
        ],
        loading: false,
      }
  });
  </script>
</html>
```

**modal.html**

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <highchart id="mychart" config="mychart"></highchart>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try to call resize(). Related topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838758/highcharts-graph-width-is-incorrect-when-scrollbar-is-present-in-bootstrap-flui and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206631/why-are-bootstrap-tabs-displaying-tab-pane-divs-with-incorrect-widths-when-using