# Bootstrap 3 modal and Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

How can I combine a responsive highcharts chart with Bootstrap 3 modals?  Can anybody help me !Thank you so much!

[image]

My JS code is here:

```
$('#highchart_hongli').highcharts('StockChart',{

                                        title:{
                                        text:'收益走势图'
                                        },
                                        xAxis:{
                                        title:{
                                        text:'入市时间'
                                        },

                                        },

                                        tooltip: {
                                        xDateFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
                                        shared: true,
                                        },

                                        rangeSelector : {
                                        selected : 8
                                        },

                                        series : [{
                                                  name : '净值',
                                                  data : {!! json_encode($hongli_data)!!},
                                                  tooltip: {
                                                  valueDecimals: 2
                                                  }
                                                  }]
                                        });
```

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="highcharts_hongli"></div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> 关闭页面</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you add the HTML Source, too?

Comment: @MartinSchneider I have upload my html code. Thanks you very much for help me.

Comment: hmm can't find anything clearly suspicious. you have to make sure that the div with the id highcharts_hongli takes up the space that you want it to. Highcharts should do the rest and display itself in whatever this div takes up. I recommend examining the measures of the div via the element inspector of your browser of choice and see if it has the desired properties.

Comment: Is your modal hidden when you create the chart? In that case, browser can not calculate width+height for the container (it's 0px x 0px), so Highcharts render the chart with default width and height. See similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398127/highcharts-wont-fit-in-bootstrap-3-modal-body

Comment: I accept your advise, and I change some part. But the charts doesn't display. This is my Js code : `var chart = $('#highchart_hongli').highcharts();
          $('#portfolioModal1').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
                               $('#highchart_hongli').css('visibility', 'hidden');
                               });
          $('#portfolioModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                               $('#highchart_hongli').css('visibility', 'initial');
                               chart.reflow();
                               });`  @PawełFus

Comment: Try to call setSize on your chart, when is loaded. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838758/highcharts-graph-width-is-incorrect-when-scrollbar-is-present-in-bootstrap-flui