# How to make Highchart fill the whole bootstrap window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I'm working with Bootstrap modal pop up window. I need to place a chart inside it and everything seems to work fine, but the chart doesn't fill the whole window. Also, what's important, the chart becomes as it must be after resizing the browser. Here's this on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TheCyberNash/khbLsozv/. I tried to add `$(window).resize();"` after creating the chart , but it didn't give any result. Thanks for any help!

Comment: See the similar topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838758/highcharts-graph-width-is-incorrect-when-scrollbar-is-present-in-bootstrap-flui

Answer (score 1):

www.jsfiddle.net/khbLsozv/2/

Simply styling the modal and the graph.

I did the stylign within the HTML, but change the %'s until you find a result you like, i just made it full screen :)

Comment: Actually, it reverses the problem. Now the chart looks correct before resizing, but after it doesn't.

Comment: Mine adjusts perfectly on my end.